# Go: Wrong coverage when there is no tests for a package

Tags: go, code-coverage, codecov, go-testing

I have a Go project with the following structure:

```
foo/foo.go
foo/foo_test.go
main.go
```

As you notice, there is no test for `main.go`.

I collect the coverage report using the following command:

```
go test ./foo ./ -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic
```

Here `./foo` and `./` show where to look for packages.

**Problem:** I send the coverage report to codecov.io which shows that my code is 100% covered with tests. But this is not true as my `main.go` has no tests at all.

It seems like the system only counts those packages that explicitly specify test files.

**Question:** How to fix the coverage report in the way that it will count information about untested packages?

*Note:* You can find my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Shpota/skmz) and the real statistic is [here](https://codecov.io/gh/Shpota/skmz). The project has a different structure, but the issue persists (wrong coverage).

Comment: Does this solve your issue? `go test -coverpkg=.,./foo -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic . ./foo`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-coverpkg` flag may be used to specify the packages that are used as the basis of coverage analyis.

Quoting from [Command go: Testing flags:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags)

> ```
> -coverpkg pattern1,pattern2,pattern3
>     Apply coverage analysis in each test to packages matching the patterns.
>     The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested.
>     See 'go help packages' for a description of package patterns.
>     Sets -cover.
> ```

So in your specific example this will do it:

```
go test -coverpkg=.,./foo -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic . ./foo
```

To apply it for a complete module / project, you may use:

```
go test -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic ./...
```

Another option is to place an "empty" test file into the folders of packages that do not currently have a test file. That way they will be naturally included in default coverage analysis, but obviously nothing will be covered from them.

See related discussion on github:

[cmd/go: go test -cover & go test -coverprofile should always output a coverage #24570](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24570)

Comment: There are problems with the coverpkg method unfortunately. If you want accurate coverage you have to place empty test files everywhere you don't have tests.

I have a repo that demonstrates the pros and cons of available workarounds [here](https://github.com/wafer-bw/go-test-cov-testing)

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
go test -coverpkg=./... -race -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic ./..
```

[image]